# magick.MagickException: No image to get image format

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

I've a code for some conversion any images via ImageMagick + JMagick. On my local PC my code work fine, but not on server. 
ImageMagick installed completly, delegates presents too. Some IM tests, such as

```
convert myfile.png -resize 500x300 111.png
```

works fine.

```
     //open template. Source is valid path to file, file exists
    ImageInfo voucherImageInfo = new ImageInfo(templateSource);
    logger.info("Create imageInfo for template '{}', result - '{}'", templateSource, voucherImageInfo);
    MagickImage voucherImage = new MagickImage(voucherImageInfo);
    logger.info("Voucher image - '{}'", voucherImage.getImageFormat());//there are exception
```

This code

```
    public Dimension getImageGeometry(String filename) throws MagickException {
    ImageInfo imageInfo = new ImageInfo(filename);
    MagickImage mi = new MagickImage(imageInfo);
    return mi.getDimension();
}
```

falls too with exception: magick.MagickException: Unable to retrieve handle

I guess some problem with JMagick, but how I can check it? I've tried re-install JMagick, but it was useless.
Any ideas?

Comment: My process has permissions for read/write this file, of corse

Comment: Are you sure that `imageInfo` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Absolutely.
In log: Create imageInfo for template '/opt/myfile.png', result - 'magick.ImageInfo@76b5bd8b'